# How to display records outside of a form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET.
Here i have a webpage with 2 sections, left and right.
I have to fill a form on the left side, and right side i have to display some records comes from database. (See the screenshot.)

In my knowledge I need to use a form tag to submit form. Same time I have to display records on the right side by using a gridview. Gridview also required a form tag,

How can i use two form tag in a asp.net page or is there any option to display records outside of form ?

I am stuck with this issue.

I welcomes your help on this problem to learn more in asp.net.

Thanks,

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnc4x.png)

Comment: Based on your wording, I assume this is ASP.NET WebForms.  If this is the case, and I'm remembering correctly, you cannot have more than one `<form>` tag per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to put 2 form tags on your aspx. All you need to do is bind the data everytime the form loads and every event you've done(for example after submitting ur new data).After that the page will load and load the data that u entered.

For example:
You can put this code inside the submit button cilcked event.

```
 Gridview1.DataSource = Yoursource;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

If u want to load the data every second, that will be different. Since aspx c# runs at server or need to postback before do anything. So ill suggest to use like ajax or the asp update panel to separately load the data every second without posting back.

Comment: Thank you very much for effort and help

Answer (score 0):

There'a a couple ways to handle this. Actually a bunch :)
When the left side is submitted, just then bind data to the right hand side. Both sets of content are under the same form tag - which you can include the form runat=server in a master page so everything is contained within.

You can use ajax to dynamically load the right hand side as well. I'll post a url here as a ref in one sec. Just create the right hand side as a user control you add into your project. If you are using MVC you can render a child action - though you don't specify.

So - in short - include all your controls within the <form runat=server> tags.

There are other ways (like the old school way of using ajax control toolkit ala http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691298/Creating-AJAX-enabled-web-forms which isn't the newer recommended way) and better ways like using single page apps and pure ajax calls but since you are starting out here, let's just keep it simple :)

Notice here the form tag is in the master page and all content is contained within the form tag. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx